# Send data to an open server socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have a socket server program running on a remote machine,I want to send data through a client socket program without creating a new socket connection everytime.
As long as the server socket is open i just need to send the data.need the java code for the same.
This is the code im currently using
Works fine the first time.Second time i run it,it says connection refused.

```
String host = "machinename";
     int port = 23000;
     InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
     //establish a socket connection with server
     socket = new Socket(address, port);
     //send msg to server
     OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
     OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
     String request = "data";

     String sendMessage = request + "\n";
     bw.write(sendMessage);
     bw.flush();
     InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
     String message = br.readLine();
```

Comment: If you don't want to create a new socket connection every time (as is probably logical), then you need to keep the original connection open. There are plenty of networking tutorials that will show you the proper way to perform socket communication.

Answer (score 0):

> Second time i run it,it says connection refused.

That can only mean that your *server*, whose code you haven't posted here, has closed the listening socket after processing one client.

Answer (score -1):

add :

> socket.setKeepAlive(true);

After your :

> socket = new Socket(address, port);

Comment: Keepalive doesn't have anything to do with 'connection refused'.